# A proposition about power series

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, power-series

Is this proposition established?

Suppose that $0<\nu<1$, $x\in[0,1]$ and absolutely converge power series
$$p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,$$
$$P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1+\nu)}a_nx^{n+\nu}.$$
Suppose that $p'(x),P'(x)$ don't exist. For any $a\in[0,1)$ and any sufficiently small $\delta>0$, there exists a certain $C>0$ such that
$$\sup_{x,y\in[a,a+\delta]}|P(x)-P(y)|\geq C\sup_{x,y\in[a,a+\delta]}|p(x)-p(y)|\delta^{\nu}. $$

Comment: What is $C$ supposed to depend on? As stated, $C$ may depend on $(a_n)$, $a$ and $\delta$, in which case such $C$ obviously exists.

Comment: It does not makes sense to assume that $p'(x)$ does not exist. If $p(x)$ converges in $(0,1)$, then the function defined by it is infinitely many times differentiable in $(0,1)$. In fact $p(x)$ extends holomorphically to the unit disk $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. This is one of the basic theorems in complex analysis. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration See also my last comment under my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P'(a)=0\neq p'(a)$, then there is no such constant. Indeed, in this situation, we have for sufficiently small $\delta$,
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x,y\in[a,a+\delta]}|P(x)-P(y)|&\ \ll_a\ \delta^2\\
\sup_{x,y\in[a,a+\delta]}|p(x)-p(y)|\delta^{\nu}&\ \gg_a\ \delta^{1+\nu}.
\end{align*}
These bounds follow readily from the Taylor series expansion of $P(x)$ and $p(x)$ around $a$. In particular, the ratio of the left hand sides tends to zero under $\delta\to 0+$, hence it is not bounded away from zero.

Comment: What if P'(x) and p'(x) do not exist?

Comment: @Burnie: They always exist for $x \ne 0$, do they not?

Comment: the convergence of Σan does not indicate a convergence of Σn*an. @Mateusz Kwaśnicki

Comment: @Burnie: Any power series is differentiable in the interior of its set of convergence. Hence $P'(a)$ and $p'(a)$ exist. More generally, if $u_n$ are holomorphic functions on an open set $M\subset\mathbb{C}$, and the function series $\sum u_n$ converges locally uniformly on $M$, then the series defines a holomorphic function on $M$, and its derivative equals $\sum u_n'$ on $M$, which itself converges locally uniformly on $M$.